# How to Remove wpmp_switcher strings from Blog URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

I was using WordPress mobile pack plugin which i have already uninstalled but there are too many URLs are indexed in Google with ?wpmp_switcher=desktop parameter. How can i fixed and no index kind of URLs or is there any plugin to fixed this

Example URL is

`http://www.example.com/contact-us/?wpmp_switcher=desktop`

Comment: Just to clarify, you removed the plugin that created these URLs, but they're still indexed and you'd like them to be removed from Google?

Comment: Yes exactly @dan Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could put in a rewrite rule that redirects to remove the query string when it contains that parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wpmp_switcher
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

This code would go in your *.htaccess* file